# systemLayoutSizeFitting(_:) does not respect width or height constraints for decimal numbers

Tags: ios, autolayout, uikit

```
let aView = UIView()
let width: CGFloat = 173.5
aView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: width).isActive = true
print(aView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(CGSize(width: width, height: 0)))
```

Output (on iOS 13.7, may affect other versions):

> (173.66666666666666, 0.0)

I've found using **0.33** or **0.66** as the fractional part makes the output slightly less wrong, but still has unwanted recurring digits e.g. 173.33333333333334 for 0.33

I've also reproduced this for height constraints. Using `UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize` as the size also has the same incorrect output.

Is this a bug, or is this something I don't know about Auto Layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIKit cannot draw on partial-pixels.

On devices with `@2x` screen scale (such as iPhone 11), your result will be:

```
(173.5, 0.0)  // nearest half-of-a-point
```

On devices with `@3x` screen scale (such as iPhone 11 Pro), your result will be:

```
(173.66666666666666, 0.0)  // nearest third-of-a-point
```

Note that if you try:

```
let width: CGFloat = 173.25
```

you'll get:

```
(173.33333333333334, 0.0)   // iPhone 11 Pro
(173.5, 0.0)                // iPhone 11
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using fractional points for views in any case. This is why CGRect has an `.integral` property.

Comment: @matt This creates some complications for what I'm currently doing then, a UICollectionView where each cell are fixed at half the width of the view (to create two columns), but they have variable height. Am I missing something or is the only solution if I want fixed width to floor the value so it's always a whole number? I'm not a huge fan of this as the spacing will in turn be slightly inaccurate.

Comment: That's certainly what I've had to do, `ceil` or `floor` type of thing.